# how to pass a object in MMWormhole?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchkit

I'm using MMWormhole framework to share data from iPhone to Apple Watch.

With MMWormhole I just send a text but I want to send a list of data.
How to share a list from iOS app to WatchKit App.

For send message, I use this:

```
 self.wormhole.passMessageObject(number, identifier: "numberIdentifier)
```

for read that data to WatchKit App I use:

```
 self.wormhole.listenForMessageWithIdentifier("letterIdentifier", listener: { (message) -> Void in
        self.lblValue.setText((message as? String))
    })
```

How is it possible to send an array?

Message to bee an array?

Comment: You can send JSON string and then parse it on other side

Comment: any example for that????